# Error when changing ownership and transferring access rights

Tags: powershell, permissions, permission-denied, user-permissions

I ran into a problem, wrote a script that compresses pdf files through a program and transfers rights to a new file by copying from the old one to differentiate access to new files.
Here is the part of the code that I have is the problem

```
$owner = $origFile.GetAccessControl().GetOwner([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
             $newFile = Get-Item -Path $PathoutFile
             $FileSecurity = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity
             $FileSecurity.SetOwner($owner)
             [System.IO.File]::SetAccessControl($newFile, $FileSecurity)
             Get-Acl -Path $origFile | Set-Acl -Path $newFile
```

My problem is this:
I execute the script using domain administrator privileges, everything works fine. If I use a domain user account and grant maximum rights to the directory, a compressed file is saved in it, and in this case I get the error “Attempt to perform an unauthorized operation.
I do not want to run the script under the administrator account for a simple reason, I believe that such rights are redundant for this operation. My judgments may not be correct, please help in solving this problem.
P.s actions are performed on a network directory.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're changing ownership, regardless how you see it, it would need Administrative permissions to perform the request when calling on the WinAPI; especially working with ACL's. There might be a solution, but I'm not aware of it. I would recommend asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). Someone may have some insight on it there. You won't get much answers here, if any, due to there being no issue with your current code; since this is a programming related website.

Comment: Hello,@AbrahamZinala.
thanks for the response and the provided links to resources, I will use your suggestion and hopefully I can find a solution to my problem. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I myself found a solution to my main problem using the NTFSSecurity PowerShell module.
The transfer of access rights was performed using the Get-NTFSAccess $filein | Add-NTFSAccess $fileout